# Reading a file with a wrong access mode in C

Tags: c, text, binary, fopen, fwrite

In a project I'm writing a file as binary, using `fopen(p_full_path, "ab");` before I start writing it.

When I read it, I noticed I was doing this in a wrong way: to open the file I used `fopen(p_full_path, "r+");` instead of `fopen(p_full_path, "rb+");`.

The content of the file is correct anyway. So I don't understand if there is a real difference between the modes `r+` and `rb+`, I mean if there is the possibility of reading the wrong content because I'm not reading the file as binary.

Reading the [documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/?kw=fopen) of `fopen()` I didn't find the answer.

Comment: *Text mode* stream (may) "suffer* an extra translation within the Standard Library code. Usually on Windows when the disk has `'0x0D'` and `'0x0A'`the stream (`fread()`, `fgets()`, ...) will receive only 1 char: `'0x0A'`

Comment: "r+" will open in the *default* mode which is usually "t". The difference is that in text mode the newline characters are converted to whatever the OS uses for line endings. If the text file is opened as binary you may not notice if the text editor is smart enough to consider different line ending. But if you want to write binary data, and are in text mode, every `0x0A` data might be converted, leading to a corrupted output.

Comment: I'm using an ESP32-S2. I don't know how it could interpret the file (e.g. like Windows). Hence, in order to avoid problems, I think I must use the correct `fopen()`. Thank you for the clarification about the differences!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on which [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform) you are using.

For example, on [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant platforms (such as Linux), there is no difference between binary mode and text mode.

However, on Microsoft Windows, the situation is very different: In binary mode, lines are terminated by character sequences of `\r\n` (carriage return followed by line feed), whereas in text mode, they are only terminated by `\n` characters. This is because `\r\n` is automatically converted to `\n` in text mode, whereas in binary mode, no conversion is performed. Also, in text mode, the character code `\x1A` is interpreted as the end of the file, whereas in binary mode, this value has no special meaning and is treated as a value like any other.

Comment: I don't know if my embedded platform (ESP32-S2) works like either Windows or Linux. However now the difference is clear!